# Proof about the coordinates of the centre of a circle which touches another circle and the $y$-axis

Tags: circles

Question 16 goes as follows:

> **16.** Given that the circle
>
> $$x^{2} + y^{2} + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$$
>
> touches the $y$-axis, prove that $f^{2} = c$.
>
> A circle, with its centre in the first quadrant, touches the $y$-axis and also touches externally the circle
>
> $$x^{2} + y^{2} - 4x = 5;$$
>
> prove that the coordinates of its centre satisfy the equation
>
> $$y^{2} = 10x + 5.$$
>
> If the circle also touches the $x$-axis, prove that the abscissa of the point of contact is $5 + \sqrt{30}$.

I have already completed the first part of this proof ([with the help of this very website](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277535/help-setting-out-a-proof-about-the-circle-x2-y2-2gx-2fy-c-0)). I thought that once I had done that, I would be able to complete the rest of the question on my own, but it was not to be.

The first thing I can do is write down what I know.

I know, from what I've proved, that the equation of this circle can be expressed in the form:

$x^{2} + y^{2} + 2gx + 2fy + f^{2} = 0$

I know that, since the circle touches the $y$-axis and has its centre in the first quadrant, the $x$-coordinate of the centre is $r$ (if $r$ is the radius of the circle).

I know that the radius of the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} - 4x = 5$ is 3 and that its centre is $(2, 0)$.

The first thing I tried to do with this information was to say: let the centre of the circle be $(r, d)$.

Then:

$(x - r)^{2} + (y - d)^{2} = r^{2} \Leftrightarrow x^{2} + y^{2} - 2rx - 2dy + d^{2} = 0$

Next I said, well, I know that there is a point $(a, b)$ that lies on both of my circles (their point of contact) and so:

$a^{2} + b^{2} - 2ra - 2db + d^{2} = 0$

And

$a^{2} + b^{2} - 4a - 5 = 0$

But all I've managed to do after all of this is give myself two simultaneous equations with four unknowns and I just can't for the life of me come up with any more useful information.

Comment: Perhaps you could construct a system, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using your symbols and their interpretation. Let $(r,d)$ be the center of the circle you are trying to find. Since it touches **externally**, therefore the distance between the centers should be equal to the sum of the radii of the two circles. This means
\begin{align*}
(r-2)^2+(d-0)^2 & = (r+3)^2\\
r^2-4r+4+d^2 & = r^2+6r+9\\
d^2 & = 10r+5.
\end{align*}

If the circle also touches the $x-$axis then $d=r$. In which case you have the quadratic equation
$$r^2-10r-5=0.$$
It has two possible roots:
$$r = \frac{10 \pm \sqrt{120}}{2}=5 \pm \sqrt{30}.$$
But $r>0$, hence $r=5 + \sqrt{30}$.

Comment: nice. you beat me to the answer.(+1)

Comment: That does all seem very neat, thank you, but I'm not quite sure I get why the distance between the centers should be equal to the sum of the radii of the two circles. I follow all of your working after that. I've just been messing around with a piece of paper and a pencil and it "feels" true, but I'm not sure I've ever seen any proof that this must always be so

Comment: As I understand it, what you're saying is true: the distance between the centers should be equal to the sum of the radii of the two circles, if the radii have the same gradient at the point of contact. That is, the two radii will form a straight line between the centres. Is that true? Because surely, if the radii met at an angle, the distance between the centres would not be the sum of the radii, you'd have to construct a triangle and find the length of the third side. So I take it we need to prove the radii form this straight line. This is because the circles are tangential to each other?

Comment: @Au101 at the tangent point the tangent line drawn is perpendicular to the radius and since that will hold for both circles, therefore the radii of both have to be perpendicular to the (same) tangent line. This means the radii will be collinear.

Comment: Lovely stuff, now we're on the same page

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to reply: doesn't showing $r = 5 + \sqrt{30}$ merely give us the value for $r$, which would be, among other things, the $x$- (and $y$-) coordinate of the centre. But the question asks for the abscissa of the point of contact, which is surely not the $x$-coordinate of the centre of the circle in this case? I'm confused

Comment: @Au101 you are absolutely right. To get the abscissa of point of contact there are few ways: one of which is to find the line that passes through the centers and then find the intersection of that line with either circles.

Comment: @AnuragA I thought that was so. My problem is, using wolfram|alpha to draw $x^2 + y^2 - 4x = 5$ I am left with a circle that it surely can't touch our circle externally, if our circle is to touch the $x$- and $y$-axis. It seems to me that something is wrong?

Comment: @Au101 It is very much possible. Please see the picture I have added to the solution.